# ¿Por que cambia el estilo del boton?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Use el metodo setStyleSheet para cambiar las caracteristicas de un boton:

```
self.registro.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {font-family: Arial; color: white; background-color: black; border-radius: 15px;}")
```

Y puse otro que cuando pasas el mause encima cambia el color y todo eso:

```
self.registro.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover {border: 2px solid red; background-color: white; color: black;}")
```

Y asi hacer ese efecto, pero lo raro es que cuando ejecuto la aplicacion debes de cambiar las caracteristicas del boton como asigne en el primer metodo setStyleSheet pone el boton por defecto de PyQt5 lo cual no entiendo por que pasa

codigo completo:

```
import sys
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon



class MainRegister(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, title):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        #Configuracion de la ventana
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("imagenes/icon.png"))
        self.setFixedSize(600, 500)
        self.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow {background-image: url(imagenes/fondo.png);}")

        #Aqui se pone el marco principal de la ventana
        frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        frame.setGeometry(80, 0, 448, 425)
        
        #Aqui creamos un ToolBotton para poner el icono de la aplicacion"
        tool_registro = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        tool_registro.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        tool_registro.setGeometry(265, 20, 71, 61)
        tool_registro.setIcon(QIcon("imagenes/icon.png"))
        tool_registro.setStyleSheet("QToolButton {background: black; border-radius: 15px;}")
        
        #La creacion de las etiquetas y botones
        etiqueta = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        etiqueta2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        etiqueta3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.nombre = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.email = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.registro = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.registro.clicked.connect(self.Enviar_Correo)
        

        #Texto de las etiquetas y botones
        etiqueta.setText("Registro:")
        etiqueta2.setText("Nombre y/o Apellido: ")
        etiqueta3.setText("Email: ")
        self.registro.setText("Registrar")

        #Texto de fondo de las entradas
        self.email.setPlaceholderText("Example@gmail.com")
        self.nombre.setPlaceholderText("Nombre Apellido")

        #Aqui se colocan las coordenadas y anchura y altura de los widgets
        etiqueta3.setGeometry(145, 275, 110, 31)
        etiqueta2.setGeometry(145, 195, 140, 31)
        etiqueta.setGeometry(145, 125, 110, 31)
        self.nombre.setGeometry(145, 235, 195, 25)
        self.email.setGeometry(145, 300, 195, 25)
        self.registro.setGeometry(145, 345, 125, 45)


        #Y aqui se usa css para modificar sus diseños y que todo se vea bonito
        frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame {background: white; border-radius: 20px;}")
        etiqueta.setStyleSheet("QLabel {color: black; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px; font-weight:bold;}")
        etiqueta2.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font-family: Arial; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;}")
        etiqueta3.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font-family: Arial; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;}")
        self.nombre.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {font-family: Arial; color: black; background: transparent; border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;}")
        self.email.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {font-family: Arial; color: black; background: transparent; border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;}")
        self.registro.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {font-family: Arial; color: white; background-color: black; border-radius: 15px;}")
        self.registro.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover {border: 2px solid red; background-color: white; color: black;}")



    

    def Enviar_Correo(self):

        user_correo = "miguelwow31@gmail.com"

        #Esto verifica si hay texto en las entradas
        if self.email.text() and self.nombre.text():
            texto_email = str(self.email.text())
            texto_nombre = str(self.email.text())

            print("Correo: {} \nNombre y Apellido: {}".format(texto_email, texto_nombre))

        else:
            print("No hay texto")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventana_principal = MainRegister("Registro-Ventana")
    ventana_principal.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Aqui capturas de pantalla para que puedan entender mejor el problema por si todavia no les quedo claro:

[image: Como pueden ver no pone el boton con las caracteristicas que le asigne en el primer setStyleSheet sino que pone el boton por defecto]

[image: Apesar de todo si provoca el efecto pero, el boton deberia ser negro con letras blancas no un boton por defecto]

Comment: A veces Qt coge los valores por defecto si un estilo no es válido. Es decir, basta con que te falle una coma, un apostrofe o algo esté mal escrito para que ocurre. Aparte de eso, deberías de investigar como implementar un archivo .QSS, de esa manera todo lo que tienes que hacer es `app.setStyleSheet(mi_archivo_qss)` para implementar el estilo a toda la aplicación, en lugar de ir control tras control (no es muy eficiente ir editando los estilos uno a uno).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El AP asume que el método [`setStyleSheet()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop) es acumulativo pero no es asi ya que usar nuevamente el método se reemplaza el contenido anterior.

La solución es establecer todo en forma unificada:

```py
self.registro.setStyleSheet(
    """
    QPushButton {font-family: Arial; color: white; background-color: black; border-radius: 15px;}
    QPushButton:hover {border: 2px solid red; background-color: white; color: black;}
    """
)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono de maravilla